# facebook changed his REST API, how to work with them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

2 or 3 months ago 
[this link works fine.](http://api-read.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=xml&method=fql.multiquery&pretty=0&queries=%7B%22page_info%22%3A%22select%20name%2Cfan_count%2Cpage_url%2Ctype%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%20IN%20(27479046178)%22%7D&sdk=joey)

but now this time page shoes some REST API error.

actual work that i want to do is,

can i generate link that shoes Facebook page details like{ page likes} without any access token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i generate link that shoes Facebook page details like{ page likes} without any access token ?

No, you can not.

Since API v2.0 all calls (expect the ones for profile pictures) require an access token.